# Can you link two (or more) web pages in Node-RED?

Tags: html, node-red

I've been creating a dashboard using html, css, and javascript using visual studio code but I want to do some modbus communication which is getting a lot more complicated than I anticipated. I started my dashboard using node-red because there are built in modbus nodes but I didn't like the built in UI interface and wanted to go fully custom.

Now I am back to node-red as I have learned you can just create your own webpage using the "http in" and "http response" nodes and I was able to see one of my pages through those. My issue is that I have multiple pages for my dashboard and I am not sure how to connect the web pages through node-red since there isn't a file structure and I can't link the http nodes together.

I have tried using two "http in" nodes on the same page, with one that has the address of the main page and on that page there is a href link to the other page, and the other with the address that is used in the href and the page details. When i click the link on my home page I see a "cannot GET" error but if I type in the url for the page itself it loads.

The two flows are not connected at all right now and I am not sure how they could be. Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit the question to show how you have configured the http-in nodes, but if you pick the right routes for the different pages this should all just work.